# Implementing Ads on tableviewcell in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to implement Ads on tableviewcell in iphone for my latest project.I browse a lot on the this topic and found that apple will reject the app if the ads is placed in a floating mode ie in tableviewcell.So i go through the mopub third party and implemented this,if the app will get reject if i use the same or is their any other options to implements this in iphone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here the ads are displaying for every 10th cell in the UITableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  int row = [indexPath row];

  // Assume that kFrequencyAdsInCells is 10 so every 10th row is an ad
  // Don't want first item to be an ad so use 10-1=9 instead of 0
  if ((row % kFrequencyAdsInCells) == (kFrequencyAdsInCells)) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AdCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Need to create a new cell object
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
                ;
    }
    cell.contentView addSubview:[AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self]];
} else {
     // make your normal cells
}


}
```

You can follow this reference [link](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/embedding-google-admob-ads-within.html).

Comment: Will my app  get rejected from appstore ,if i implement the ads like this.

Comment: Most of them are using AdMob Ads. But don't know exactly will it be accepted or rejected.